# How to program an Onclick for HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How does one program on-click multiple functions together. The code used to come up with this question will be provided shortly.

Now for clarification, my aim is to click either one of the links provided, and I want it to move to a certain element's spot. I want to make the host element disappear and then want an iframe to open up. While this happens I want all the other links in Row(one)(two)(three) to some how move away or fade away until the link is clicked again. I understand this requires some sort of Jquery, so if anyone has a Jquery, please provide me with one? I haven't been able to develop my own, nor find one. I give much appreciation to anyone willing to help me!

```
<div id="external_links">
<ul id="Rowone">
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.chiefdelphi.com/forums/portal.php" title="ChiefDelphi - Forums"><h3>Chief Delphi</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="Rowtwo">
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="Rowthree">
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<iframe src="http://www.dptv.org/programs/robotics/index.shtml?cmpgn=shorturl" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
    </div>

    </div>

</div> 
<!--#external_links-->
```

Comment: Here you go: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: Go learn to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It should provide you with all the tools to do what you need. Doing things like moving/fading elements is actually pretty complex, but JavaScript libraries like jQuery will do the heavy lifting for you. I know [Codecademy has a jQuery course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery), and others may be able to recommend other/better learning resources.

Comment: FelixKling Hmmm I'll go check that out ^_^
DaoWen OHH my friend recommended me this before I started with my website :O I've been looking for it ever since! THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to:

`<a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor" OnClick="myfunction()">`

And add call the function in your js file or on your script tag zone.

```
function myfunction(){
    ifrm = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME"); 
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://stackoverflow.com/");
}
```

If you want a fade effect in javascript it's not so much easy. Use jQuery for that.

Comment: Well that helped me... a bit :) It's good enough I think I'll get some help from other commentors, Thanks so much!

Comment: If you're using _jQuery_ correctly then you don't need to add the `onclick` attribute to your anchor (`<a>` tag), nor do you have to write a separate function `myFunction`, nor would you use `document.getElementsByTagName` since you can just use [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Seriously, just go through the [jQuery tutorial on Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery). It'll take you maybe a couple hours, but you'll find it so useful!

Comment: @MomoCoolBreezyKitty - I forgot to tag you in my comment, so you probably didn't get a notification. Read what I said above—I really think jQuery will make your life easier.

Comment: Okay, I shall! I'd love to become a multi-platform programmer one day :) although it's getting me in a few places ^_^